# How to get data only if date is more than 45 days in aggregate mongoose?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I want to get data based on date which is not  exceeded 45 days only. I am using aggregation and I have a column postdate so I want to get data only if postdate is within 45 days.

below code postdate is column name:

```
const baseStages = [
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: CrewbiesJobs.collection.name,
      localField: "jobId",
      foreignField: "jobId",
      as: "job_docs"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$job_docs"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      jobTitle: 1,
      jobId: 1,
      // jobDescription: 1,
      postedDate: 1,
      filter1: 1,
      filter2: 1,
      filter3: 1,
      createdAt: 1,
      updatedAt: 1
    }
  },
  { $match: filter },
  { $sort: { postedDate: -1 } }
];

const jobsStages = [
  ...baseStages,
  { $skip: query.skip },
  { $limit: query.limit }
];

let jobsAggregate = await Jobs.aggregate(jobsStages);
```

And here is my mongoose schema:

```
let jobsSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    jobTitle: String,
    jobId: {
      type: Schema.Types.String,
      unique: true,
      dropDups: true,
      ref: "Jobs"
    },
    jobDescription: String,
    postedDate: String,
    filter1: [{ label: String, value: String }],
    filter2: [{ label: String, value: String }],
    filter3: [{ label: String, value: String }]
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

Comment: Please share collection

Comment: `let jobsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    jobTitle: String,
    jobId: { type: Schema.Types.String, unique: true, dropDups: true, ref: 'Jobs' },
    jobDescription: String,
    postedDate: String,
    filter1: [
        {
            label: String,
            value: String
        }
    ],
    filter2: [
        {
            label: String,
            value: String
        }
    ],
    filter3: [
        {
            label: String,
            value: String
        }
    ]
}, { timestamps: true });`

Comment: am getting data all data from two collections but now i want to get data .based on postDate which is not exceeded 45 days

Comment: Please share collection data at jsoneditor ( https://jsoneditoronline.org/)